# how to add displaymenber and value menber to listbox

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

i need to get listbox value menber to be the combobox selected value 
And for the listbox display menber to be combobox selected text 
i have tried this

```
            List<SomeData> data = new List<SomeData>();
        data.Add(new SomeData() { Value = contactIDComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), Text = contactIDComboBox1.SelectedText });
        contactPositionListBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
        contactPositionListBox1.ValueMember = "Value";


            if (!contactPositionListBox1.Items.Contains(contactIDComboBox1.SelectedValue))
            {
                contactPositionListBox1.Items.Add(contactIDComboBox1.SelectedValue);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD A `LIST<INT>` LIKE THIS `public List<int> contactIDList = new List<int>();`

THEN ADD TEXT TO THE LISTBOX

```
      if (contactIDComboBox1.SelectedIndex!=-1 && contactIDComboBox1.SelectedValue!=null)
       {

            if (!contactPositionListBox1.Items.Contains(contactIDComboBox1.Text))
            {
                contactPositionListBox1.Items.Add(contactIDComboBox1.Text);
                contactIDList.Add((int)contactIDComboBox1.SelectedValue);


            }

        }
    }
```

THEN  ADD THIS

```
                        if(contactIDList.Count>0)
                        {
                            newContactPosition.PositionID = value;
                            for (int add = 0; add < contactIDList.Count; add++)
                            {
                                newContactPosition.ContactID = contactIDList[add];
                                ContactPositionDB.AddContactPosition(newContactPosition);
                            }
                        }
```